# loops and recalling variables in Python. I'm coding a guessing game using a random number generator

Tags: python-3.x, loops, variables, while-loop, nested-loops

I'm creating a guessing game using a random number generator in python. Not for school, just for fun as a hobby. I have the basics coded out, but I'm stuck. I'm trying to reuse a few variables using loops, and I just can't figure it out. I am reading my book "Starting out with Python" 3rd edition, but I'm still stuck. I will clean up the code as I learn more and advance. Here is the code I have so far.

```
import random

answer = random.randint(0,9)
guess = int(input('Take a guess. '))
print(guess)
print(answer)
if guess == answer:
    print('You win!')
elif guess < answer:
    print('Too low!')
elif guess > answer:
    print('Too high!')
```

Please remember I'm new to this and still learning and teaching myself, I'm not in school.
Anyway, what I'm trying to achieve right now is to reuse my variables using a loop. After the elif statements I want the user to be able to try again using the variables I've created with needing to run the code again. I'm also wanting the player to have three guesses and if they guess wrong after 3 tries then it's the next persons turn. And if they guess right, the program end and moves on to the player. I'm not asking for someone to write the code for me, I'm just asking for some help, advice, and/or some small example code. I'm not great at learning from books, I learn better by watching. More of a hands on approach with examples and whatnot. I will always refer to my book first. TIA.

I've read my book, looked for examples online, tried coding it myself. I'm just can't seem to figure it out. I'm stuck. As I have explained in the first part, I'm still learning and sometimes the way the book teaches just doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if the following works for you

```
import random

answer = random.randint(0,9)

print(answer)

num_guess = 1


while True:
    guess = int(input('Take a guess. '))
    
    if num_guess < 3:
        if guess == answer:
            print('You win!')
            break
        elif guess < answer:
            print('Too low!')
        elif guess > answer:
            print('Too high!')
        
    else:
        num_guess = 0
        print('Next players turn')
    
    num_guess += 1
```

Comment: The code worked, but the random number printed before the user could have a chance to make a guess. Now this is not a problem if the player is not looking at the screen. But if the screen is in view of the player/user then it is an issue. I'm wanting the player to guess a number before the random number is generated. I did figure out the answer to my question later on after I asked it. Here is my code so far. it will become better with time.

Comment: import random

answer = random.randint(1,50)

print('Guess a number between 1 and 50')

guess = int(input('Take a guess. '))

while(guess<50):
    
    if(guess == answer):
        print('You win!')
        break
    elif(guess < answer):
        print('Too low!')
        guess = int(input('Guess again '))
    elif(guess > answer):
        print('Too high!')
        guess = int(input('Guess again '))

Answer (score -1):

This code is far more efficient than the current answer:

```
import random

    def game():
      
      answer = random.randint(0,9)
      for i in range(3, -1, -1):
        
        guess = int(input(f'Take a guess. You Have {i} Tries left'))
        print(guess)
        if guess is answer:
          print('You win!')
          play_again()
        elif guess < answer:
          print('Too low!')
        elif guess > answer:
          print('Too high!')
        
        if i == 0:
          print(f"You ran out of tries. The correct number was {answer}")
          quit()
    
    
      
      
      
    def play_again():
      pa = input("Play again? Yes or No?")
      
      if pa.lower().startswith('y'):
        game()
      else:
        quit()
      
    game()
```

I got rid of you printing the answer every time you reran the program. I put your code into a for loop that decrements the amount of tries you have. I made 2 functions that act as repeating your program so you don't have to keep rerunning it. I apologize if the changes I made didn't fit what you expected.